# How do I retrieve objects based on which cell was clicked?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a friend system with all the friends in a collection view. Currently I can click on the cell and the information on that cell will transfer over to the new view controller. From that view controller there is a button to go to a table view. I want to retrieve all the objects from parse within the Pointer class that has the user id matching the user you clicked the cell on. I am passing the username to the page. Below is the code for getting objects only for the logged in user. How would I do this for other users?

Below is the pointer class
[image]

Below is the User class
[image]

```
 func getSongs(){
    let retrieve = PFQuery(className: "Pointer")
    retrieve.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        var object = objects as! [PFObject]
        if(error == nil){

            //self.titleofsong = []
            //self.artist = []

            for i in 0...object.count-1{
                //self.ret.append(object[i].valueForKey("user") as! String)

                if (object[i].valueForKey("user")!.objectId == currentUserID){
                    //print(object[i].valueForKey("title") as! String)
                    self.titleofsong.append(object[i].valueForKey("title") as! String)
                    self.artist.append(object[i].valueForKey("artist") as! String)
                    print("friends song \(self.titleofsong)")
                    print("friends artist \(self.artist)")
                }
            }
        }

    })

}
```

Below is the code for passing the friends info to the next view controller.

```
  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: friendcellView = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("friendcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! friendcellView




    cell.friendname.text = arrayOfFriendsNames[indexPath.item]
    cell.friendpic.image =  arrayOfFriends[indexPath.item]
    cell.friendpic.layer.cornerRadius = cell.friendpic.frame.size.width/2;
    cell.friendpic.clipsToBounds = true



    return cell
}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("Cell \(indexPath.item) selected")
    print(arrayOfFriendsNames[indexPath.item])
     self.dicSelected = ["friendname" : arrayOfFriendsNames[indexPath.item], "friendimage" :  arrayOfFriends[indexPath.item]]
    print("didSelected before prepareForSegue \(self.dicSelected)")

    self.selectedData.text = arrayOfFriendsNames[indexPath.item] as? String
    self.selectedData.image = arrayOfFriends[indexPath.item] as? UIImage

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("friendaccess", sender: selectedData)
}

  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "friendaccess"){

        let nextViewOBJ = segue.destinationViewController as! FriendProfile
       nextViewOBJ.dataModel = self.selectedData;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please the code where `didselectrowatindexpath` and `cellforrowatindexpath`.

Comment: It's clear now. I will upvote and hope someone can help you.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to prepare model class and store all your friends list details in that class and then store that model class object into collection view array.

After that retrieve object from array and display in collection view.

Once its done. Now if you want to go another view controller when user select cell then get index path and from on that basis you will get model class object from your collection view.

Now pass this object on another view controller and do whatever u want.

This things works successfully...do it.